Can a specialized assembly instruction be designed to shift memory block and simplify array insertion and deletion?
While learning about array operations, I've found that insertion and deletion can be cumbersome, requiring shifting elements one by one. Could we design a specialized assembly instruction that shifts a block of memory between two specified addresses by a certain number of positions (if the parameters are too much, storing the addresses and the number of positions in dedicated registers)? Upon executing this instruction, the CPU would notify a standalone memory shifting hardware, which could then quickly complete the memory shift. Would this approach reduce the complexity of array insertions and deletions to O(1)?
I have asked some AI but didn't get satisfying answer

Big-O is a notion of algorithmic complexity (how an algorithm trends with large and infinitely large input), not hardware performance.  So, introducing a second processor to do some of the work won't change the Big-O done by the algorithm as a whole.  However, not counting part of the algorithm can change the Big-O, as can the definition of an "operation", i.e. what is and what isn't an operation being counted.

I'd like to learn more about this memory shifting hardware that can transfer an arbitrary number of bytes in constant time. GPUs could take great advantage of this when doing block transfers.

@Raymond Chen just a beautiful imagine from a beginner(qaq

I'm assuming we're talking about time (or clock cycles) complexity, not number of instructions, because instructions per cycle is highly variable especially when you include very long-running instructions that do a lot of work.
An instruction that does a huge amount of work (like x86 rep movsb is memmove) doesn't reduce the amount of cache / memory bandwidth required.  With a dedicated state machine1 that allowed out-of-order exec to go far past it (unlike actual Intel / AMD CPUs where it's microcoded, taking over the front-end), yes it potentially could give speedups if the surrounding code doesn't otherwise bottleneck on memory accesses.
But you couldn't say it makes the cost O(1) time; that's only sort of true if you do it infrequently enough for out-of-order exec to do it in parallel with the main bottleneck.
The big-O complexity model doesn't really account for the possibility of instruction-level parallelism.  You just count the operations and assume that costs add in some way.  But since you ignore constant factors, this probably still works.  If the number of copies is a larger complexity class than anything else in the algorithm, then as n approaches infinity, the ratio of copies to other work will also tend towards infinity, so will definitely be a bottleneck even if the copy size is small and fixed.
Or if the total copy size summed across the number of copies is a larger complexity class, then again you'll have more copying work than any other kind of work, so it won't be able to "hide" in the shadow of other operations.
But if the total amount of copying is a smaller complexity class than other bottlenecks, as n tends toward infinity it will become negligible.  Parallelism could make the difference between n^2 + n vs. n^2 time if you have n copies and n^2 other work, but those are both in the O(n^2) complexity class because smaller exponents become insignificant as n approaches infinity.

Footnote 1: Andy Glew, architect of the fast-strings microcode in Intel's P6 microarchitecture, later regretted not building dedicated hardware to handle it.  (Before Pentium Pro, the first P6 CPU, rep string operations were just handled one unit at a time, like actually repeating movsd, so was pretty slow.  So fast-strings microcode, copying like 8 bytes per 1 or 2 clock cycles if it hits in cache, was still a big improvement.)
